# Making ubuntu installation with mac terminal

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, live-usb, mac

I'm trying to create a dual boot for Ubuntu and Windows 7. Currently I only have a macbook with OS 10.7.5 installed, this means that I have to use the terminal in order to create an Ubuntu booting USB for live booting. 
According to a website I found I need to do the following:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /Volumes/NO NAME.img /Users/Thijs/downloads/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

However this returns the error :

```
hdiutil: convert: only a single input file can be specified
Usage:  hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>
    hdiutil convert -help
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /Volumes/"NO NAME.img" /Users/Thijs/downloads/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

OR

```
hdiutil convert -format Rdxx -o /Volumes/"NO NAME.img" /Users/Thijs/downloads/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Comment: Alright it seems to have at least done something.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "~" and never try to to convert it on same folder ,  Use Rdxx instead of UDRW  as.

```
hdiutil convert -format Rdxx -o /Volumes/"NO NAME.img" /ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

hope it will work.

Comment: sorry that gives the same error, However I have modified the version a bit (now posted) and made it work from download folder.

Comment: how did the above command work without using "" quotes.?

Comment: worked for many ,check http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/links/convert-iso-to-img-using-hdiutil-under-mac-os-via-installationfromusbstick-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: filename with space are enclosed within double quotes,otherwise it won't work.see my post.